# Pandas Groupby: Aggregations on the same column but totals based on two different critera / dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My Dataframe:

```
display_name    security_type1  currency_str     state
         A            GOVT           USD         Done
         B            CORP           NZD         Passed
         B            CORP           USD         Done
         C            CORP           EUR         Done
         C            CORP           EUR         Traded Away
         C            CORP           GBP         Done
         C            CORP           GBP         Done
         C            CORP           USD         Done
```

My derired result is to:

a. Groupby `display_name`, `security_type1`and `currency_str`

b. Then count the number of rows where `column state` contains `Done` and update column `Done_RFQ`

c. Display the total count of rows for each  `display_name`, `security_type1`and `currency_str` combination and update column `Total_RFQ`

d. and finally display the percentage of Done to total count i.e. `Done_Pct = Done_RFQ / Total_RFQ`

```
display_name    security_type1  currency_str   Done_RFQ Total_RFQ Done_Pct
A               GOVT             USD           1           1      100%
B               CORP             USD           1           2      50%
C               CORP             EUR           1           5      20%
C               CORP             GBP           2           5      40%
C               CORP             USD           1           5      20%
```

My code which works with the exception of the `Total_RFQ` hence `Done_Pct` as well

```
d = [('Done_RFQ', 'size')]
df_Done_Client = df[
                    df['state'].str.contains('Done')
                ][['display_name','security_type1','currency_str','state']].copy()

df_Done_Client =    
    df_Done_Client.groupby(['display_name','security_type1','currency_str'])['state'].agg(d).reset_index()
    # Sum of all Done RFQ's per display_name
    Sum_of_Done_For_Month = df_Done_Client.groupby('display_name')['Done_RFQ'].transform('sum')
    df_Done_Client['Total_Done_RFQ'] = Sum_of_Done_For_Month
    df_Done_Client['Done_Pct'] = df_Done_Client['Done_RFQ_For_Month'].div(Sum_of_Done_For_Month).round(5)
    display(df_Done_Client)
```

I'm unclear as how to calculate this total as it needs to come from another dataframe i.e. same fields but without the 'Done' criteria.

```
df_All_Client = df[['display_name','security_type1','currency_str','state']].copy()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need `Total_RFQ` column with `size` - total counts and `Done_RFQ` by count by boolean mask - compare with `Done` and `sum` of `True`s:

```
d = [('Total_RFQ', 'size'), ('Done_RFQ', lambda x: x.eq('Done').sum())]
df=df.groupby(['display_name','security_type1','currency_str'])['state'].agg(d).reset_index()
df['Done_Pct'] = df['Done_RFQ'] / df['Total_RFQ'] * 100
print (df)
  display_name security_type1 currency_str  Total_RFQ  Done_RFQ  Done_Pct
0            A           GOVT          USD          1         1     100.0
1            B           CORP          NZD          1         0       0.0
2            B           CORP          USD          1         1     100.0
3            C           CORP          EUR          2         1      50.0
4            C           CORP          GBP          2         2     100.0
5            C           CORP          USD          1         1     100.0
```

If need check substrings:

```
d = [('Total_RFQ', 'size'), ('Done_RFQ', lambda x: x.str.contains('Done').sum())]
df=df.groupby(['display_name','security_type1','currency_str'])['state'].agg(d).reset_index()
df['Done_Pct'] = df['Done_RFQ'] / df['Total_RFQ'] * 100
print (df)
  display_name security_type1 currency_str  Total_RFQ  Done_RFQ  Done_Pct
0            A           GOVT          USD          1         1     100.0
1            B           CORP          NZD          1         0       0.0
2            B           CORP          USD          1         1     100.0
3            C           CORP          EUR          2         1      50.0
4            C           CORP          GBP          2         2     100.0
5            C           CORP          USD          1         1     100.0
```

Comment: Works!! The state column can have 'Done' and 'Tied Done' which we would want to include. It appears the .contains method is not available. What could x.eq be updated to so as to inculde any string with 'Done' in it?

Comment: @PeterLucas - It depends what need, if need check substrings better is `x.str.contains('Done').sum()`, if need check strings `x.eq('Done').sum()`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. Similar to @jezrael's solution, but keeps your logic to check for substring `Done` and filters for `Done_RFQ > 0`.

In addition, I believe you need 2 `groupby` calculations for your desired result, i.e. `Total_RFQ` is calculated by `display_name`.

```
# function to calcuate Done_RFQ
d = {'Done_RFQ': lambda x: x.str.contains('Done', na=False, regex=False).sum()}

# apply 2 groupby calculations
df['Total_RFQ'] = df.groupby('display_name')['display_name'].transform('size')

group_cols = ['display_name', 'security_type1', 'currency_str', 'Total_RFQ']
res = df.groupby(group_cols)['state'].agg(d).reset_index()

# calculate Done_Pct
res['Done_Pct'] = res['Done_RFQ'] / res['Total_RFQ']

# filter for Done_RFQ > 0
res = res[res['Done_RFQ'] > 0]

print(res)

  display_name security_type1 currency_str  Total_RFQ  Done_RFQ  Done_Pct
0            A           GOVT          USD          1         1       1.0
2            B           CORP          USD          2         1       0.5
3            C           CORP          EUR          5         1       0.2
4            C           CORP          GBP          5         2       0.4
5            C           CORP          USD          5         1       0.2
```